# Typing in Hindi does not work after event postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-api, hindi

I am using google API to write Hindi text on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
                destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled: true
            };
            var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);   
            control.makeTransliteratable(['<%= Page.FindControl("txtName").ClientID %>']);    
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);       
</script>
```

And to toggle from Hindi to English or vice-versa, I use (Ctrl+g) as you can see.

Everything work fine, but after I hit a dropdown event, it stops working and all other defined textboxes for writing in hindi stops working.

I have my page inside UpdatePanel and only Submit button is in the trigger.

Comment: do you use partial postack using updatepanel and scriptmanager ?

Comment: Yes I am using Update Panel and ToolkitScriptManager

Comment: remove that and see, you will understand why its failed....

Comment: I have also tried to call "google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);" on the event like "ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad); ", true);", but it also doesn't work

Comment: do what i ask....

Comment: Yes its working, So,that means it will not work inside update panel, but it will hinder all my page design, i.e. page loader, and after every postback event I have to use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true", which is not right

Comment: search google now, how to fix your issue... now you know where to fix...  Happy Coding...